# My SQL 5.7.33 Error Code - 1126. Can't open shared library

Tags: mysql, data-masking

I am using aws RDS Mysql. I am trying to install data_masking plugin using below commands. I am referring the [Mysql 5.7 reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-masking-installation.html)

```
INSTALL PLUGIN data_masking SONAME 'data_masking.so';
CREATE FUNCTION mask_inner RETURNS STRING
  SONAME 'data_masking.so';
CREATE FUNCTION mask_outer RETURNS STRING
  SONAME 'data_masking.so';
```

But after execution of first line I am getting error 1126. Can't open shared library..
I am doing this first time so I don't know if I am making any mistake here or what is missing.

Comment: Where is data_masking.so? Is it in a place that mysql will find it and has permission to open it? Are all of the data_masking.so dependencies in place too? Try running `ldd data_masking.so` to check.

Comment: do you mean I first need this file then only it can be installed? I was assuming that it should be there and I have to just install.

Comment: Yes, I think INSTALL here means "load it into MySQL" and not download the file from somewhere else., if that's what you meant? I don't know if this should be included with MySQL Enterprise by default or not sorry. I'd check your MySQL plugin directory to see if it's there or not.

Comment: I got the answer. data_masking is available only for Enterprise Edition. This is not available in community edition.